# Wordpress Best Practice Coding / Slimming Down Templates

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Wondering if anybody has any guides or insight in to best practice coding / cutting down the code of Wordpress sites as I believe many off the shelf templates are code heavy.

What methods of proofing do you use to ensure a site loads as fast as possible and is running at its best capacity?

I use tools such as Firebug & CSSLint to check for errors but there is only so much that these can do.

Comment: There are absolutely loads of tutorials on this, optimize wordpress, caching, optimize images for screen size, server caching, browser caching (expire headers), pre-fetching resources, above the fold content, compression, minify js/css, defer loading of js/css so non blocking.

Comment: Thank you David, I have read plenty and would just like to know what are the proven to be most efficent, industry standard methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. My ground rule: Minimize PHP and custom php functions. But, not everything can be achieved by using WordPress built in functions. So, choose what are really need. Can WordPress do it with its functions? If not, chalk it up to plain bad luck.
2. Never calculate the same variable twice in a WordPress template.
3. Never load a library twice in a WordPress template.
4. Cache on the fly results of intense calculations by using $_SESSIONS
5. If your gut says that something is inefficient, there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Genesis framework to me seems to follow a practice that is different to most of the themes I have seen so far. It prints HTML on events, that fire other events, and so on... in a very strict way. It basically continues the action-driven kernel of WordPress. In Genesis you have basically no 'PHP templates' like in all of the other themes and it seems faster in most cases. In my opinion it's worth a look at.
2. More about general setup: Temporarily use e.g. P3 plugin to check for plugins that are not that performant.
3. Use a caching plugin.
4. For websites in general: Use e.g. GTMetrics to insight page speeds etc.